# Use Alpine JS to conditionally add CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, alpine.js

Using Alpine JS, is there a way to check for sub menus and toggle a class on the parent `nav`?

I know how to toggle the value of `x-data` with a click event, is there something I can add to the nested `ul` to switch the value of `x-data` from `false` to `true`?

Here's an example:

```
<nav x-data="{subOne: false, subTwo: false}" :class="{ 'has-sub-menu-1': subOne, 'has-sub-menu-2': subTwo}">        
   <ul>
      <li>Menu Item
         <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu 1
               <ul>
                  <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
               <ul>
            </li>
         <ul>
      </li>
   <ul>
</nav>
```

I'd like to be able to toggle `x-data` values to `true` if there are sub menus.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough context in your question to be sure what you are trying to achieve, but I assume you just want subOne to be true when there is a Sub Menu 1, and subTwo to be true when Sub Menu 2 exists.

If you are generating the menu from the backend, why not do something like

```html
<nav class="{{ $menuItem->getSubMenu() ? 'has-sub-menu-1' : '' }}{{ $menuItem->getSubMenu()?->getSubMenu() ? ' has-sub-menu-2' : '' }}"> 
  <ul>
    <li>{{ $menuItem->name }}</li>
    @if ($subMenuItem = $menuItem->getSubMenu())
      <ul>
        <li>{{ $subMenuItem->name }}
          @if ($subMenuItemTwo = $subMenuItem->getSubMenu())
            <ul>
              <li>{{ $subMenuItemTwo->name }}</li>
            </ul>
          @endif
        </li>
      </ul>
    @endif
</nav>
```

If you are using AlpineJS to actually build the menu from some data source, please include the complete code. In this case, you can build the condition for `:class` from the data structure you have.

It's actually very hard to give you any suggestions without knowing how the menu is generated, but the pseudoish code above should give you an idea of what your options are.

(Please note that above code uses PHP 8 syntax, if you use Laravel you can use `optional($menuItem->getSubMenu())->getSubMenu()` instead).